# Bootstrap break points use @media?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out the best way to do this:

Currently I have 4 columns (col-sm-3) on my website.

The problem is that 'SM' breaks at 768px which is way too much width for what i want at the smallest size.

Is the best way to go about it to make @media queries for different sizes and set the col-sm-(SOMETHING) at the different @media sizes? or can i do it some other way

Comment: Bootstrap uses media queries at `768px`, `992px` and `1200px`. The two options I would recommend are making your own media query for the width you need, or make your own class to get the desired results.

Comment: to be clear though your saying that using different col sizes at different media events is the way to go?